# Render element onClick event, React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm wondering how to make a component like what Ant design did with their **message, notification**, etc component.
[image]

```
import { message, Button } from 'antd';

const info = () => {
  // How to make component / api like this?
  message.info('This is a normal message');
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Button type="primary" onClick={info}>
    Display normal message
  </Button>,
  mountNode,
);
```

Compared to other common library or our own, usually we need to explicitly place the component where we want the component to show.

**Other framework**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Button type="primary" onClick={showMessage}>
      Display normal message
    </Button>

    {/* Others need to do this */}
    <Message active={messageStatus} content="Lorem ipsum" />
  </div>,
  mountNode
);
```

I checked [their github](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/tree/master/components/message), but I can't understand the code since they are using typescript and a lot of abstraction.
Also tried using React.createElement() method, but still couldn't figured out how to put the created element to the dom tree.

Comment: Seems like they're using a package called [rc-notification](https://github.com/react-component/notification)

Comment: Yeaa I saw that too, now im curious what the rc-notification really did. is it has something to do with the rendering component

Comment: It looks like they appended a `div` element on either the root container or the parent container element, and from there, they added the notification(s) to the div. Note, the notification themselves are wrapped in a div, which are wrapped by a CSSMotionList. I'm not too familiar with this CSSMotionList but it looks like its a CSS animation component that animates the notifications to appear/disappear. The component also looks like it's made by the same group of developers.

Comment: Nice catch. Thanks

Comment: Btw I tried the same tehcnique, it's working. I create a basic sample https://prnt.sc/v468dl Still wondering how the getContainer() work on this line github.com/react-component/notification/blob/master/src/… When I see the property definition of the getContainer, it's still not clear for me

Comment: That's just a function that returns an HTML element. It's an optional parameter for the Notification instance. If you look at their [docs](https://github.com/react-component/notification#api), it says getContainer is a "function returning html node which will act as notification container". The [code](https://github.com/react-component/notification/blob/master/src/Notification.tsx#L59) supports this description too.

Comment: So in the end the created notification will be injected using document.body.appendChild(el)?

Comment: Seems like it, unless you provide your own function to get the container of your choice.